# Zsh clear command line from zsh/sched call

Tags: command-line, zsh, scheduling, zle

I try the following:

```
clear-cmdline() {
    zle && zle kill-buffer
    sched +3 clear-cmdline
}
sched +3 clear-cmdline
```

After I run this code, I enter a few letters at prompt, and wait. Nothing happens. Unless I continue typing, then the command line gets cleared. How to obtain desired effect of just clear of the command line?

Comment: Hmm, per the docs "Commands are executed either immediately before a prompt, or while the shell's line editor is waiting for input." so in theory it should run while you're twiddling your thumbs...

Answer (score 2):

It does work. It's just that the prompt is not redrawn until the next time you type something. Add a `zle -R` to redraw the prompt:

```
clear-cmdline() {
  zle && zle kill-buffer && zle -R
  sched +3 clear-cmdline
}
sched +3 clear-cmdline
```